# 3 Counting Instances of Unique Value in Field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table similar containing fields like `country`, `region`, `town`.
I'm trying to create a query that counts the number of unique towns by region and by country.
i.e. if there are two records where town="Newtown", I need to see a count of 1 for Newtown not 2.

The following query displays a count of the number of records containing a given town, but not the number of unique towns.

```
SELECT COUNT(town) AS numb, `country`, `region`, `town` 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `country`, `region`, `town`
```

Anyone know how I do this?

Comment: you need count(distinct town) which'll dedupe

Comment: Please accept the answer that solved the question - don't leave your unanswered question open, with no conclusion, and an illogical title. If it's not one of the below answers _write the answer yourself and accept it_.

Answer (score 2):

Use `distinct` in your `count()`

```
SELECT `country`, `region`, COUNT(distinct town) AS numb
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `country`, `region`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Count(Distinct town)
```